# TypeError when attempting cross validation in sklearn

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I really need some help but am new to programming so please forgive my general ignorance. I am trying to perform cross-validation on a data set using ordinary least squares regression from scikit as the estimator.

Here is my code:

```
from sklearn import cross_validation, linear_model
import numpy as np

X_digits = x
Y_digits = list(np.array(y).reshape(-1,))

loo = cross_validation.LeaveOneOut(len(Y_digits))

# Make sure it works
for train_indices, test_indices in loo:
    print('Train: %s | test: %s' % (train_indices, test_indices))

regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

[regr.fit(X_digits[train], Y_digits[train]).score(X_digits[test], Y_digits[test]) for train, test in loo]
```

When I run this I get an error:

```
**TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index**
```

This should be referring to my x values which are lists of 0s and 1s - each list represents a categorical variable which has been encoded using OneHotEncoder.

With this in mind - is there any advice on how to get around this problem?

Fitting a regression estimator to this data seemed to work, although I got a lot of very large / odd looking coefficients. To be honest this whole journey into sklearn to attempt some kind of categorical linear regression has been totally fraught and I welcome any advice at this point.

**EDIT 2 sorry i tried another method and put that error callback up by mistake:**

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-be578cbe0327> in <module>()
     16 regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
     17 
---> 18 [regr.fit(X_digits[train], Y_digits[train]).score(X_digits[test], Y_digits[test]) for train, test in loo]

TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index
```

**EDIT 3 adding an example of my independent variable (x) data:**

```
print x[1]
[ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
```

**EDIT 4 Attempt to convert lists to arrays, met with error:**

```
X_digits = np.array(x)
Y_digits = np.array(y)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-ea8b84f0005f> in <module>()
     14 
     15 
---> 16 [regr.fit(X_digits[train], Y_digits[train]).score(X_digits[test], Y_digits[test]) for train, test in loo]

C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in score(self, X, y)
    320 
    321         from .metrics import r2_score
--> 322         return r2_score(y, self.predict(X))
    323 
    324 

C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\metrics.py in r2_score(y_true, y_pred)
   2184 
   2185     if len(y_true) == 1:
-> 2186         raise ValueError("r2_score can only be computed given more than one"
   2187                          " sample.")
   2188     numerator = ((y_true - y_pred) ** 2).sum(dtype=np.float64)

ValueError: r2_score can only be computed given more than one sample.
```

Comment: Could you show the whole traceback (error message) please?

Comment: sure thing! Will update main post now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cross-validation iterators return indices for use in indexing into numpy arrays, but your data are plain Python lists.  Python lists don't support the fancy kinds of indexing that numpy arrays do.  You're seeing this error because Python is trying to interpret `train` and `test` as something that it can use to index into a list, and is unable to do so.  You need to use numpy arrays instead of lists for your `X_digits` and `Y_digits`.  (Alternatively, you could extract the given indices with a list comprehension or the like, but since scikit is going to convert to numpy anyway, you might as well use numpy in the first place.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice - I will update my post based on your comments. I received another error after converting my lists to arrays: ValueError: r2_score can only be computed given more than one sample.

Comment: You are only leaving one sample out. You can't calculate `r^2` on only one sample. Use a different cross validation fold object, such as `KFold`.

Comment: Ah yes, of course - I just realised that I should be using the MSE parameter here (in the model selection phase)!

Comment: You can also convert your plain Python list to a Numpy array using np.array(my_python_list)